# How to sort a customized listview alphabatically?

Tags: java, android

I have a customlist view with an ImageView and a textview. I am retrieving that list view by this method:

```
private List<Currency> getModel() {
        List<Currency> list = new ArrayList<Currency>();
        for (int i = 0; i < countryCode.length; i++) {

            list.add(get(countryCode[i], flag[i]));
        }


        return list;
    }
```

this method returns a list of an image and a textview in a particular list item, and I am setting this in a adapter to show it in a listview. But how can I sort this list by alphabetically comparing with the text of that text view in the list? I have tried this

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
    });
```

but this method only works for string types list, but my list is not in string type? What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to compare in this way

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Currency>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Currency c1, Currency c2) {
            return c1.getCurrencyName().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getCurrencyName());
        }
    })
```

Comment: Yess, this one Worked, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Currency>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Currency s1, Currency s2) {
            return s1.compareTo(s2); 
        }
});
```

Don't forget to implement  `Comparable<Currency>` interface in order to implement the `compareTo(Currency o);` the way you want it.

Comment: Read about Comparable interface here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `list` contains `Currency` objects, so you will need to create a comparator that compares `Currency`. Now, I am not sure what kind of `Currency` class are using, but if it is the one [from the standard JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html), then it has a `getCurrencyCode()` method that returns a string (or you can use the `countryCode` you're passing into `get()` invocation).

Then, you just create a `Comparator` instance like this:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Currency>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Currency s1, Currency s2) {
        return s1.getCurrencyCode()
                 .compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getCurrencyCode());
    }
});
```

Note, that the `return` clause does not have to do the string comparison. What you have to do is basically return a value that is less than zero if you think `s1` is "smaller" than `s2`, or a value that is greater than zero, if you think it's "greater" than `s2` (or return zero if they are equal). The comparison algorithm is up to you.